# Is there an error log for the visual studio android emulator?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, android-emulator

I am trying to debug my app on the visual studio android emulator.

The emulator successfully boots and other pre-built apps work.  I can connect and browse the internet with the emulator.

My app appears in the app list, but its (sole) activity name appears, instead of the app name.

When I click on it, I get the "Unfortunately [app-name] has stopped" message.

I have a breakpoint set for the activity's OnCreate method, which never gets hit.

Is there an error log that I can access that contains the details of what caused this error? Or is there some kind of mode that can be activated so that I can get a stack-trace?

Running Windows 10 x64 Pro